# Android, recovered Timestamp from firestore

Tags: android

[image]
How can I get the time from cloud firestore? I tried this

**EDIT**

> In my model class I have this : 
>   @ServerTimestamp
>      private java.util.Date datesend;

Firestore has managed the time and date for me now, I want to retrieve the time from firestore and display it in my recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You also have to store timestamp in your data model as a field to retrieve it, I don't think that database does auto timestamp for you.

Comment: After several attempts, here is how I was able to recover:                                                
        Date date1 = model.getDatesend();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        holder.date.setText(dateFormat.format(date1));

Answer (score 0):

Convert a Timestamp to a Date, use the `toDate()` method on the Timestamp.

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = localDateFormat.format(messageclass.getDatesend().toDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but toDate () is in red, as in the picture